# How can I modify the clouds the OpenNI gets?

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbdslamv2, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find the file containing the cloud to modify. For example, I want to paint all planes in red and show in the final Cloud.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201078/how-can-i-modify-the-clouds-the-openni-gets?/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either save them as PLY files and use a software like [meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) or write your own tools in PCL

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0